# Bash delete all symbols before last 2 "/" symbols in variable

Tags: bash, variables, sed

Struggling. Please help.

```
a="/var/www/test/some/page3.html"
```

I need to transform it to

```
a="some/page3.html"
```

I'm trying

```
a=$(sed "s~/var/www/test/~~g" $a)
```

But getting baaaad results.

Comment: try `a=$(sed 's~/var/www/test/~~g' <<< "$a")`

Comment: Thank you! I'm dumb as a box of rocks

Comment: Much more efficient to use a PE-based fix, like that Paul shows, and avoid using process substitutions (and external tools like `sed`). See also [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), and https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Note that heredocs and herestrings create temporary files -- if your `$TMPDIR` is on a memory-backed filesystem it can be very efficient, but it's still not free.

Comment: With awk: `a=$(awk -v FS='/' '{print $(NF-1) FS $NF}' <<< "$a")`

Comment: Thank you Cyrus for a hint about accepting answers. I am learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bash parameter parsing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
No need to run a subprocess.

```
$: a="/var/www/test/some/page3.html"
$: echo "${a%/*/*}"      # the part you want to get rid of
/var/www/test
$: echo "${a#${a%/*/*}}" # strip that
/some/page3.html
```

If you want to get rid of that leading slash as well...

```
$: echo "${a#${a%/*/*}/}"
some/page3.html
```

Comment: Thank you! I like it very much

Comment: If it worked for you, could you accept the solution?

Comment: Just did. I am new here. My apologies

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful! But of course it is akin to say that water is wet. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a="/var/www/test/some/page3.html"
a=$(basename $(dirname "$a"))/$(basename "$a")
echo "$a"
```

Output:

```
some/page3.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to print the last 2 path sections:

```
$ a='/var/www/test/some/page3.html'
$ [[ $a =~ [^/]+/[^/]+$ ]] && a="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
$ echo "$a"
some/page3.html
```

Use this if you want to remove the first 3 path sections:

```
$ a="/var/www/test/some/page3.html"
$ [[ $a =~ ^(/[^/]+){3}/(.*) ]] && a="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
$ echo "$a"
some/page3.html
```

Idk which you want to do as both approaches will produce the expected output from that one sample input. Choose what you want done given this:

```
$ a="/foo/var/www/test/some/page3.html"

$ [[ $a =~ [^/]+/[^/]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
some/page3.html

$ [[ $a =~ ^(/[^/]+){3}/(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
test/some/page3.html
```

Comment: Ed, that's beautiful. :)